# Zend Youtube API - Upload Videos on a Single Account?

Tags: php, youtube-api, zend-gdata

I want to allow anyone register on my site, to upload their videos on my own youtube user channel.

I don't want them to comment any videos, or anything that requires their own login credentials.

Should I use: ClientLogin authorization ?

If so, how can I get a token so that I can allow my site to interact with my youtube channel account?

Any lights here will be greatly appreciated, since I'm kinda lost here.

Answer (score 3):

I have accomplished this using ClientLogin. A basic class is below. This class returns an instance of Zend HTTP Client that is ready to make authenticated requests.

```
<?php

class GoogleAuthenticator {

  public static function authenticate($logger) {
    $tokenObj = new Token();
    try {
      $token = $tokenObj->get($token_name);
      if(!empty($token)) {
        //load a new HTTP client with our token
        $logger->info('Using cached token: ' . $token);
        $httpClient = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();
        $httpClient->setConfig(array(
                'maxredirects'    => 0,
                'strictredirects' => true,
                'useragent' => 'uploader/v1' . ' Zend_Framework_Gdata/' . Zend_Version::VERSION
            )
        );
        $httpClient->setClientLoginToken($token);
        //attempt to use our token to make an authenticated request. If the token is invalid
        // an exception will be raised and we can catch this below
        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, 'uploader/v1', '', $youtube_api_key);
        $query = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoQuery();
        $query->setFeedType('top rated');
        $query->setMaxResults(1);
        $yt->getPlaylistListFeed(null, $query); //ignore the response!
      } else {    
        $logger->info('Generating new HTTP client');  
        // Need to create a brand new client+authentication
        $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';
        $httpClient = 
                Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                        $username = YOUTUBE_USERNAME_PROD,
                        $password = YOUTUBE_PASSWORD_PROD,
                        $service = 'youtube',
                        $client = null,
                        $source = 'uploader/v1', 
                        $loginToken = null,
                        $loginCaptcha = null,
                        $authenticationURL);

        // get the token so we can cache it for later
        $token = $httpClient->getClientLoginToken();
        $tokenObj->destroy($token_name);
        $tokenObj->insert($token, $token_name);
      }
      return $httpClient;

    }catch(Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $e) {
      $tokenObj->destroy($token_name);
        die("Google Authentication error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }catch(Exception $e) {
      $tokenObj->destroy($token_name);
        die("General error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
  } // authenticate()
} // GoogleAuthenticator

?>
```

You'll need to have these constants defined:

```
YOUTUBE_USERNAME_PROD
YOUTUBE_PASSWORD_PROD
```

Or modify the class to pass them in. The try/catch is needed because tokens can expire, so you need to a way to refresh them. Also, you need to make a dummy request to ensure the Token is valid even after you create it.

Keep in mind that YouTube (well, as of 2 years ago or so) prevented you from uploading a video more of than every 10 minutes, which makes your use-case pretty difficult. That is, you cannot allow multiple videos being uploaded on a single accounts behalf, more of than every 10 min. But YouTube might have lifted this since then. Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, November is far away now, but I will wait for another project were this question may arise again - I can't verify the answer, but I'm sure it will help me (and others) somehow. I do have specific questions about it, but I must leave them for another time unfortunately. Cheers, and thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find any complete solutions for API V3 in the documentation I've been exploring the Internet for a solution. In the end I ported the Python example to PHP and wrote a blog post about it for other people that have the same problem:

[Uploading a video to youtube through api version 3 in PHP](http://codersopinion.com/blog/uploading-a-video-to-youtube-through-api-version-3-in-php/)

This blogpost uses the Youtube V3 api with OAuth2 so you don't have to worry about it being deprecated. All other functions (ClientLogin, AuthSub and OAuth 1.0) in V2 are **all deprecated as of April 20, 2012**.

Comment: that embedded link isn't good anymore. I found this Q&A from another question's "Related" references, as an FYI.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for commenting. I resolved the link.